# Calling blocks on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to run the block on background thread, but once it enter the block it is converting the background thread in to main thread.

Code:

```
dispatch_queue_priority_t priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), ^(void){
        [self getLinks:completion];
        [self getPhoneNumbers:completion];
        [self getUrls:completion];
    });

- (void)getLinks:(links)completion
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    "Check current thread here using po dispatch_get_current_queue()"
//Result: <OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.background-qos[0x10eaa5a00] = { xrefcnt = 0x80000000, refcnt = 0x80000000, suspend_cnt = 0x0, locked = 1, target = [0x0], width = 0x7fff, running = 0x1, barrier = 0 }>

    [MainLinks retrieveLinksWithSuccess:^(response *LinksResponse){

  "Check current thread here using po dispatch_get_current_queue()"
//Result: <OS_dispatch_queue: com.apple.main-thread[0x10eaa5780] = { xrefcnt = 0x80000000, refcnt = 0x80000000, suspend_cnt = 0x0, locked = 1, , thread = 0x607 >

        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.clientLinks = [LinksResponse getClintLinks];
        [strongSelf processFiles];
        [strongSelf finishLinksCompletion:completion];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

I want the methods which i am calling inside block also want to run on background, I am not sure what I did wrong and which makes them to push it on main thread.

retrieveLinksWithSuccess code:

```
 [self getDataUsingEndpoint:@"links"
                        tokens:@{@"linkid" : AuthenticationService.sharedInstance.userid.urlEncode ?: @""}
                    parameters:@{@"site" : @"coupon"}
                       success:success
                       failure:failure];
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that's being executed in `[MainLinks retrieveLinksWithSuccess:]`?

Comment: `retrieveLinksWithSuccess` must be dispatching the success block on the main thread.  Either modify this class or re-dispatch to the background from your success block

Comment: i am on dispatch it on main thread